# What is roswww and how does it relate to Rosbridge?

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was exploring the rosbridge package and noticed a package called roswww. Is that just the package that rosbridge uses for server logic (connection management)?

I haven't been able to find any documentation on roswww..

Can someone point me somewhere for more information, or explain what roswww *is* / what role it plays in the rosbridge package?

Thanks,
-James

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62324/what-is-roswww-and-how-does-it-relate-to-rosbridge?/) by [Souldier](https://answers.ros.org/users/4820/souldier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 198 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roswww is a deprecated package in Fuerte that was used for serving files with a web server using the ROS file system. That is, when running, you could access files in a ROS package with something like: http://localhost:8080/my_package/launch/mylaunch.launch

In essence, it had no real relationship to rosbridge and hence was removed.

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3